# Laravel + Angular 4

Tags: laravel, angular, hosting

I want to create some project and use there Laravel as API and Angular 4 to represent my site.
Since I have no money for experiments, I found [hostinger.co.uk](http://hostinger.co.uk) where I can set up php framework and do that I need.
I started configuring Laravel and get confused - where to place my site on angular? I'll have the only one site address. So I'd like to make it combined, because I need Laravel the only for working with DB.

Comment: No money is required - you can develop locally, on your own computer. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead As for using Angular with it, [Googling "laravel angular"](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+angular) should get you plenty of tutorials and example codebases.

Comment: I want to deploy it.

Comment: Eventually, sure. It's silly to *develop* remotely, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz I cannot understand you. What did you mean _develop remotely_ ? I just want to use it not only locally.

Comment: You mentioned hosting and deployment. I'm saying figure those out later - you're not at the point where you need them if you're asking how to start an app from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to keep api & frontend seperate.
If you insist on using single domain, such as *example.com* you can use subdomain `api.example.com` for **API**, and main domain for presenting your site.

On a shared hosting you can place folders something like these:

```
/api -- laravel installation(with subdomain api.example.com)
<angular build files>
index.php
script.bundle.js
style.bundle.js
etc.
......
.....
.....
.....
```

For development you can keep your angular files anywhere on your local system, and upload only build distribution to the main domain.